# Android how to create notification that resumes activity

Tags: java, android

I a have a notification in a receiver that fires off fine, but it restarts the activity (thus clearing the edittexts and resetting the toggle button) How can i set it so that when its tapped on it resumes the activity rather that clearing and resetting everything? My current code doesnt work.

Current Code

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        Intent intenti= new Intent(context, Locator.class);
        intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intenti, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.xxxxxxnotifyicon)
                        .setContentTitle("xxxxxxx Link")
                        .setContentText("Auto Check In Complete at " + currentDateTimeString);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

with:

```
intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT should use an existing activity instance instead of creating a new one.

Note however that even if the above will work for you, it will still be risky (e.g. it will break if you
activity calls finish()). A starter solution should involve saving & of activity's state into shared preferences and loading it on start. Read more [here](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.co.il/2014/01/How-to-use-Shared-Preferences-and-manage-User-Sessions.html).